# How do I create an object of an Android Project PageRenderer class in my main solution in a cross platform xamarin project?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2022

I have a background image on my start page that is being stretched to fit the screen when the app runs.
I'm trying to avoid this stretching since it looks awful.

I created a Page Renderer class inside the android project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Page), typeof(CustomPageRenderer))]

namespace ChoiceBasedStoryGame.Droid
{
    public class CustomPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public CustomPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            
            var activity = this.Context as Activity;
            activity.Window.SetBackgroundDrawable(Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.cyberpunk_hacker));

            var imageView = activity.FindViewById<ImageView>(Android.Resource.Id.Content);
            imageView.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to reference this in my start page:

```
namespace ChoiceBasedStoryGame
{
    public class StartPage : ContentPage
    {
        public StartPage()
        {
            var renderer = new CustomPageRenderer(this.Context);
            this.BackgroundImageSource = "cyberpunk_hacker.png";
            this.Renderer = new CustomPageRenderer(this.Context);
```

I'm getting errors with the namespace 'CustomPageRenderer' not existing.

But this gives a similar error with 'Droid'. I verified the reference was correct in the android properties.

I've tried adding the 'using' at the top:

```
using ChoiceBasedStoryGame.Droid;
```

Is there an easier way to set the scale for a background image to not stretch?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't create the Renderer directly. The attribute `[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Page), typeof(CustomPageRenderer))]` tells Maui that when cross-platform code creates a Maui `Page`, when on Android, render that via `CustomPageRenderer`.  See [Using Custom Renderers](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Using-Custom-Renderers-in-.NET-MAUI). NOTE: `Renderer` is backwards compatible with Xamarin.Forms (except for namespace changes). [Custom Handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize?view=net-maui-7.0) is newer Maui technique. Not many examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, if you want to use the custom renderer only for the StartPage, you can change the `[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Page), typeof(CustomPageRenderer))]` to the `[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(StartPage), typeof(CustomPageRenderer))]`.

And you can check the [official document about the Customizing a ContentPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/contentpage#creating-the-page-renderer-on-android) for more details.

In addition, there are many other methods about how to set the page's background image appropriately. Such as you can [use the image control in the grid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71405799/17455524) as my old answer did. You can also refer to this case about [changing aspect ratio of background image in Xamarin.Forms while keeping contents centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62925624/changing-aspect-ratio-of-background-image-in-xamarin-forms-while-keeping-content)